Angular 17 - How to use async values in object using new @if syntax
In the previous *ngIf directives we were able to chain multiple async operations to not repeat the async pipe in the template but to reuse them later as one subscription, now I want to use the same behavior using the new @if syntax provided in Angular 17, is it possible?
Old way:
<ng-container *ngIf="{
   test: test$ | async,
   anotherOne: anotherOne$ | async,
   // and so on...
} as data">
  <span *ngIf="data.test.length">Show something</span>
</ng-container

I want to replace the code above to use only @if statement
@if({
   test: test$ | async,
   anotherOne: anotherOne$ | async,
   // it doesn't work that way
} as data) {
   <!-- show something -->
}


You need the ; (semicolon) before as.
@if({ test: test$ | async, anotherOne: anotherOne$ | async }; as data) { 
  <!-- show something -->
}

Reference: Angular - @if (Description)
Demo @ StackBlitz

Yeah that's the character I was missing :D It works! Thanks!

Yeah I was searching in the wrong tab that's why I couldn't find it in the official documentation, it's under Reference tab also for the new documenation, https://angular.dev/api/core/@if
